# Rebuild company kardex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am trying to rebuild my company kardex. I need to use "Average Cost Method" that is supposed to consider average cost for each transaction on its specific datetime.

I have a simple table with all incoming/outgoing inventory transactions (all moves).

Every incoming transaction (purchases) are correctly priced because I take unit cost from its corresponing invoice.

The problem: 
All sales transactions (outgoing inventory) has NO unit cost (because I need to rebuild those costs).
I know I can use cursors, but we all know about performance issues there.

I have prepared a simple data to better explain myself.
Please notice that all sales (outgoing transactions) has NO cost, and I think using simple windowed functions is not going to help because each row depends on previous calculation. So, I kind of need a calculation based on previous calculation..??

```
DECLARE @Resultado TABLE (Row_ID BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Inventory_Name VARCHAR(100), Transaction_Date DATETIME, DIRECTION BIT, Transaction_Name VARCHAR(100),Transaction_Quantity INT, Transaction_UnitCost NUMERIC(18,2), Transaction_Amount NUMERIC(18,2), AVERAGE_UNITCOST_AT_TRANSACTION_DATE NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO @Resultado ( Inventory_Name , Transaction_Date , DIRECTION , Transaction_Name , Transaction_Quantity , Transaction_UnitCost, Transaction_Amount, AVERAGE_UNITCOST_AT_TRANSACTION_DATE)
SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-01', 1, 'INCOMING PRODUCT; PRUCHASE', 100, 10, 100 * 10, 10
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-02', 1, 'INCOMING PRODUCT; PURCHASE', 105, 11, 105 * 11, 10.51
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-03', 1, 'INCOMING PRODUCT; PURCHASE', 110, 12, 110 * 12, 11.03
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-04', 0, 'OUTGOING PRODUCT; SALES', -200, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-05', 0, 'OUTGOING PRODUCT; SALES', -50, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-06', 1, 'INCOMING PRODUCT; PURCHASE', 110, 10, 110 * 10, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-07', 0, 'OUTGOING PRODUCT; SALES', -20, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-08', 0, 'OUTGOING PRODUCT; SALES', -20, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'COMPUTER', '2017-01-09', 0, 'OUTGOING PRODUCT; SALES', -20, NULL, NULL, NULL

SELECT * FROM @Resultado
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Standard

Comment: Nice work on test data,Please add expected results as text and explain along with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: It would have been helpful if you had included expected results in your question.

This Common Table Expression (CTE) should get you started:

```
with CTE as (
  select Row_Id, Inventory_Name, Transaction_Date, Direction, Transaction_Name,
    Transaction_Quantity, Transaction_UnitCost,
    Transaction_Quantity as QuantityOnHand,
    Transaction_UnitCost as AverageUnitCost
    from @Resultado
    where Direction = 1 and Row_Id = 1 -- Starting condition for your single product sample data.
  union all
  select R.Row_ID, R.Inventory_Name, R.Transaction_Date, R.Direction, R.Transaction_Name,
    R.Transaction_Quantity, R.Transaction_UnitCost,
    -- The   TransactionQuantity   is already signed, so there is no need to multiple it by   ( Direction * 2 - 1 ) .
    CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.Transaction_Quantity,
    -- My accounting is pretty rusty, but this should do some sort of useful averaging.
    Cast( case
      when R.Direction = 0 then CTE.AverageUnitCost -- Sales don't affect the average unit cost.
      else ( CTE.AverageUnitCost * CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.Transaction_UnitCost * R.Transaction_Quantity ) /
        ( CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.Transaction_Quantity ) end
      as Numeric(18,2) )
    from CTE inner join
      @Resultado as R on R.Row_Id = CTE.Row_Id + 1 -- Row by row.
    )
  select Row_Id, Inventory_Name, Transaction_Date, Direction, Transaction_Name, Transaction_Quantity, Transaction_UnitCost,
    QuantityOnHand, AverageUnitCost
    from CTE;
```

You can run it against you sample data after adding a semicolon to the end of your `select` statement.

Performance is likely to be poor since you need to start calculations form the first row. Adding columns to maintain the `QuantityOnHand` and `AveragreUnitCost` would allow you to update the data as new transactions occur, e.g. in a trigger. (Note that updates and deletions may require recalculating from the beginning of time.)

A more modern solution would use [`Lead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql)/[`Lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql), but I happen to be back at SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I confirm this query to be the solution I was looking for. THAN YOU VERY MUCH. I did some minor changes because I have to adapt it to some specific scenarios in my database, but this query made it all possible. Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: @LuisGilbert I'm glad it pointed you in the write direction. Accepting answers is part of the etiquette at StackOverflow. See [How Does Accepting An Answer Work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Sorry. I'm new posting questions. Answer accepted. Thanks again!